# Can we compress and decompress an HDFS directory (with multiple files) and get the initiall directory tree after decompression?

Tags: bash, compression, hdfs, gzip, archive

I have an HDFS directory (with multiple files) and I want to compress this directory without writing the files to the local file system. Later on I want to decompress the zipped file and get the same initial directory tree which was there before compression. Can this be achieved?

The problem I am facing is everytime I do decompression, I get a single file (which has the same size as before compression) but is not splittable. So I am unable to get the individual files. Archiving the HDFS directory and then compressing and decompressing it is giving the same result and I am unable to get the individual files.

Comment: exactly what arguments are you providing, when you make the calls?

Comment: For compression: I am providig an input directory with all the files: IN_DIR=/tmp/uncompressed
and then an OUT_DIR=/tmp/compressed which will have the compressed .gz file. 


For decompression:
I am providing an IN_DIR=/tmp/compressed with the compressed file. And an OUT_DIR=/tmp/decompressed which will have the initial files.

Comment: Please include the code in your question. Many people do not read the comments.